# Show that $G$ is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

How do I show that $G$ is nilpotent given that if $G$ is polycyclic and $G$ is residually finite p-group?

Comment: "residually finite $p$-group" is ambiguous.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695431/why-is-a-polycyclic-group-that-is-residually-finite-p-group-nilpotent

Answer (score 1):

Note that $H'H^p=\Phi(H)$. Thus you have $[G', G]\le \Phi(H) \le \Phi(G)$.  That means $G/\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent; use this to show $G$ is nilpotent.

(Assuming $G$ is finite.)

Comment: sorry, what is $\Phi(H)$? Is $\Phi(G)=G'G^p$?

Comment: @JeremyH: the Frattini subgroup.  And no, in general, that relation only holds for $p$-groups.

Comment: why does this mean $G/\Phi(H)$ is nilpotent? I haven't learned the Frattini subgroup, so I am not too familiar with this. Hope it is alright if you could explain it a bit more? thank you!

Comment: @JeremyH: I've shown that $[G', G]\le\Phi(G)$, so in the quotient $G/\Phi(G)$, the third entry in the commutator series vanishes.  That's the definition of nilpotent.

Comment: Right, I think I got this. how do I show that $G$ is nilpotent from there?

Comment: @SteveD Since residual finiteness is one of the hypotheses, it does not make much sense to assume that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt: the question has been completely changed!